Pros and Cons of Not Using ForeignKey in Django Through Table?
I'm working on a Django project and came across a design pattern that I'm unsure about. I have an intermediary table (through table) that connects Book and Tag. Instead of using ForeignKey fields for the relationships, the table uses plain IntegerField fields to store the IDs of the related models (book_id and tag_id).
Here’s what the model looks like:
class BookTagType(models.Model):
    book_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    tag_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "book_tag_types"
        managed = False

This model stores just the IDs of Book and Tag, but I’m wondering:
Is there any reason or benefit not to use ForeignKey here instead of IntegerField?
What are the potential drawbacks or advantages of using IntegerField for these relations compared to using ForeignKey?

What happens if a Book is deleted?  With a ForeignKey you can do something like on_delete=models.CASCADE to handle this.

@raphael Yes, There will be also problem with data integrity and writing queries. I don't know if there is any benefit designing database like this

There are 3 reasons I can come up with:

Referential Integrity: If a related model (eg. Book) were deleted, the IntegerField would reference a non-existent row.  This could lead to a corrupted DB, which is a nightmare to deal with...
Indexs: Django automatically indexes ForeignKey fields.  The vast majority of FK relations should have an index, so you will have to manually add them yourself
ORM Features: ForeignKey fields provide convenient access to related models, and they make writing queries much easier.  For example, a FK lookup normally looks like this: name=book_tag_type.book.name, but with an IntegerField, your query becomes: name=Book.objects.get(pk=book_tag_type.book_id).name


The first one outweights the other two together tenfold. I've seen databases with worthless data because "the database ran faster without foreign key constraints".
